# How is FormsAuthentication class been implemented? How to see its source?

Tags: asp.net, form-authentication

I am just curious to findout how the System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication class is been implemented. I therefore opened  C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.dll in Reflector but this class methods are not showing any code. This class is not derived from any another class and its a sealed class. If I see empty code like following in the reflector, what does this mean? How the login and logout functionlaity actually work in this case.

```
public static void SetAuthCookie(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie)
{
}

public static void SignOut()
{
}
```

Comment: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Web/Security/FormsAuthentication@cs/1305376/FormsAuthentication@cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference Assemblies only contain metadata, not real code (mostly used by Visual Studio for when referencing assemblies).

Using Reflector, you need to do File | Open Global Assembly Cache and get System.Web from there, after having unloaded the other System.Web from Reference Assemblies.